# Badge oneboxer for chat

Tags: script, chat, badges

This script makes it possible for badges to onebox in Chat.

[image]

---

## Example format:

```
that's a [badge:nice-answer] on a powershell bountied question
```

The only *somewhat* custom one you can use is Strunk & White, in which case I had to strip out the ampersand and an extra space, resulting in `[badge:strunk-white]`.

---

### Things that I'm working on:

- Tag badges
- Custom badges, currently working, but displays a black colour
- Making them actual buttons

---

### Install:

Requires Tamper/GreaseMonkey. Click [here](https://github.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer/raw/master/badge-oneboxer.user.js) to install.

---

### GitHub:

[It's on GitHub too!](https://github.com/The-Quill/badge-oneboxer)

---

### Review:

If you want to read reviews or review the code behind this, see [the question on Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116753/badge-oneboxer-for-chat-se)!

Comment: Will the highlighting for badges be implemented as well? (hover over a tag [like this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26828353#26828353) to see what I mean)

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I'm not 100% yet... the rollovers require links and the links are a little hard to do per site ([see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/include-badge-names-as-query-strings-on-the-badge-pages)), but I'm working on a solution

Comment: The userscript also has a few problems on Safari 9, at least, I left an issue report on the Github page.